# Recode values from a data frame column as missings in R

Tags: r

I have a variable from a data frame, which contains the following statement: "Immigrants should be required to adjust to the customs of Germany". The categories of the variable are strongly agree, agree, neither, disagree, strongly disagree. Here is a frequency table of the variable:

```
> count(dat, 'c2a')
                c2a freq
1             agree  201
2          disagree  214
3           neither  156
4         no answer   15
5    strongly agree   65
6 strongly disagree  138
```

I would like to recode the variable from text to numbers. I do it the following way:

```
library(dplyr)
dat$c2a <- recode(dat$c2a, 'strongly disagree' = 1, 'disagree' = 2, 
                  'neither' = 3, 'agree' = 4, 'strongly agree' = 5)
```

But then I get the following warning message from R:
Warning message:
*Unreplaced values treated as NA as .x is not compatible. Please specify replacements exhaustively or supply .default*

How can I specify that all values of c2a which are different from 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 are NAs?

Comment: Add `.default = NA_real_` in `recode`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values are already `NA` to make it explicit and make warning go away add `.default` argument in `recode`.

```
dplyr::recode(dat$c2a,'strongly disagree' = 1, 'disagree' = 2, 'neither' = 3, 
              'agree' = 4, 'strongly agree' = 5, .default = NA_real_)
```